# python adding text between existed lines in txt_file

Tags: python

I'm trying make a simple diary program for practice. Want to add lines whenever i write a diary. diary will keep get input before gets 'Finish' or 'finish' in line

```
contents[0] Diary_file

contents[1] 'empty'

contents[2] 'Start line'

contents[3] '----------------------------'

contents[4] Diary No.1 **<- first diary starts from here**

contents[5] "I had a good day
...

===============================

(for counting logic)

diary counts                    
0
```

---

CODE

```
def writing():
content = (raw_input("> "))
return content

def put_between(word):
    with open("D_diary.txt", 'r') as read_file: # before start, get last diary
        contents = read_file.readlines()        # get contents in list
        for i in contents:
            if i == 'finish' or i == 'Finish':  #get the last diary finish line
                finish_line = i                 #to get next starting point
            else:
                finish_line = 2                 #for starting the first diary
        count = contents[-1]                    #getting the diary count number
        print count                             #for creating 'Diary No.%d' %count

    **contents.insert(finish_line+2, word)        #THIS IS THE ACTUAL PROBLEM  
    in_contents = []                            #TRYING TO START WRITING FROM
    with open("D_diary", "w") as write_file:    #
        for i in contents:
            in_contents += '\n'.join(contents) #ERROR PART
            write_file.write(in_contents)**

def writing_logic():
    one_weather = raw_input("Weather : ")                          
    print "Write your Day! -Type 'finish' or 'Finish' to stop\n"  
    while True:
        word = writing()                        #func (just raw_input)
        if word == 'finish' or word == 'Finish':
            break                                   #finish getting text
        else:
            put_between(word)                       #goes up to func
```

Error:

> *TypeError: sequence item 4: expected string, NoneType found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `put_between` function, you are setting `finish_line` to `i`, and later doing `finish_line+2`. But the `i` variable is used in `for i in contents`, which means it is sometimes (`finish_line = i`) a line of text, and sometimes (`finish_line = 2`) an integer.

You probably should use the `.index()` method to search for the word `finish`, since your code indicates that it is the only word on the line:

```
for text in ('Finish', 'finish'):
    try:
        finish_line = contents.index(text)
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
else:
    finish_line = 2
```

You are pulling `count` from the text, but not converting it to an integer. You will need to use `count = int(...)` to get an integer, so that you can do `count += 1` later to increment it.

You can probably get the output written by joining on newline:

```
outfile.write('\n'.join(contents))
```

or

```
print('\n'.join(contents), file=outfile)
```

Comment: Getting the text is good now. Still writing to the text file not worked, I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `writing()` method is returning `None`

Can you please post the code to that method as well?

Comment: yeah, i also forgot to put return on typing method. Thaanks!